# SQL Automatic Derived field

Tags: mysql, sql, derived

Ok, I'm looking for a way to make a certain field be equal to the sum of 3 other fields. I have 3 different rating fields, and then an 'overall rating' field, which I need to be automatically equal the sum of the other 3. I know how to retrieve the value using a select statement, I just want it to happen automatically in the table.
-Using MySQL

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  Some let you define a computed column on the table, for others (eg MySQL) you'd need to use a trigger.

Comment: since postgresql doesn't support computed columns either (the other popular free database), it is very likely that you will need to use other functionality. Eg. using views or triggers. If you just need to select the column, its better just to do it in a select statement. If you need to sort it for efficiency, create an index on an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do this in different DBMSes, for example Virtual Columns,

in Oracle:

```
overall NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (rating1 + rating2 + rating3) VIRTUAL
```

in SQL Server:

```
[overall] AS (rating1 + rating2 + rating3) PERSISTED
```

Unfortunatelly not all DBMSes support virtual columns. The most generic (working on most DBMSes) way to do this, and yet probably the best for your needs (no database structural change needed) is creating a view, for example like:

```
CREATE VIEW ratings_overall AS 
   SELECT rating1, rating2, rating3, (rating1 + rating2 + rating3) as overall
   FROM source_table;
```

Comment: Im using MySQL, and I already have column set in the table, exactly what query would I need to run to get it to work, or will it work at all? The create view works well, it would be just nicer to have it in the same table

Comment: You can do two things, one is to put the proper value while inserting (`INSERT INTO your_table (..., rating1, rating2, rating3, overall) VALUES (..., 13, 15, 54, (13 + 15 + 54))`) or updating (`UPDATE your_table SET ..., rating2=20, overall=(13 + 20 + 54)`, you could actually use columns names in that expression as MySQL evaluates this statement from left to right, but it is not a good practise); the other way to do this is bulk update called periodicaly (`UPDATE your_table SET overall=rating + rating2 + rating3`, with possible WHERE condition if you are able to differentiate rows to update).

Comment: Unless you are working on some VLDB like Data Warehouse either way is not a good solution. Views are made for this kind of tasks and you should use them. In current situation you will have redundancy and possible unconsistancy.

Comment: So views is the way to go. Thanks everybody